# Conceptual question: A confidence interval around the mean for t-values

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, graph-theory

I have a weighted graph of an airport network, where each node is an airport (associated with an `N`, or the number of flights landing at or leaving the airport). The weight of each edge is the number of flights between two airports. Thus, I have an associated t-value for each edge, that assesses the extent to which the observed "weight" between two airports, is non-random, given the `N` values of either airport connected by the edge.

I am now focusing on a single airport, and want to know if *in general*, the number of flights to and from it to all other airports, is within the statistical limits of randomness, or not. In other words, I want to know if the weights of all edges starting from that airport are on average, more or less than what one would expect, given the `N`'s for every pair of corresponding vertices connected by every edge.

Is a 95% confidence interval of the mean of the t-values of all edges from that airport a good way to capture that intuition?